# connect RedisInsight to redis database deployed in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm, minikube, pulumi

so I have deploy redis database service in minikube with helm chart bitnami

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/redis

but I'm unable to connect it with redisinsight

```py
kubectl get services --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE              NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default                kubernetes                  ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  2d10h
default                redisinsight-service        LoadBalancer   10.103.32.34     <pending>     80:31196/TCP             40m
kube-system            kube-dns                    ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   2d10h
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP      10.106.115.247   <none>        8000/TCP                 2d10h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP      10.111.250.58    <none>        80/TCP                   2d10h
prefect                prefect-postgresql          ClusterIP      10.106.145.244   <none>        5432/TCP                 39h
prefect                prefect-postgresql-hl       ClusterIP      None             <none>        5432/TCP                 39h
prefect                prefect-server              ClusterIP      10.110.247.9     <none>        4200/TCP                 39h
redis                  redis-headless              ClusterIP      None             <none>        6379/TCP                 10h
redis                  redis-master                ClusterIP      10.96.27.187     <none>        6379/TCP                 10h
redis                  redis-replicas              ClusterIP      10.104.12.70     <none>        6379/TCP                 10h

kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE     IP             NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default                redisinsight-9dc76bb66-hhf75                 1/1     Running   0               12h     10.244.0.17    minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-5d78c9869d-kth76                     1/1     Running   0               2d22h   10.244.0.2     minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            etcd-minikube                                1/1     Running   0               2d22h   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-apiserver-minikube                      1/1     Running   0               2d22h   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-minikube             1/1     Running   0               2d22h   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-m8zht                             1/1     Running   0               2d22h   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-scheduler-minikube                      1/1     Running   0               2d22h   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            storage-provisioner                          1/1     Running   1 (2d22h ago)   2d22h   192.168.49.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-5dd9cbfd69-lsj94   1/1     Running   0               2d22h   10.244.0.4     minikube   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-5c5cfc8747-j66x2        1/1     Running   0               2d22h   10.244.0.3     minikube   <none>           <none>
local-path-storage     local-path-provisioner-bf548cc96-q2vb4       1/1     Running   0               15h     10.244.0.16    minikube   <none>           <none>
prefect                prefect-postgresql-0                         1/1     Running   0               2d3h    10.244.0.10    minikube   <none>           <none>
prefect                prefect-server-6f58d4bd95-rbh5c              1/1     Running   0               2d3h    10.244.0.11    minikube   <none>           <none>
redis                  redis-master-0                               1/1     Running   0               22h     10.244.0.13    minikube   <none>           <none>
redis                  redis-replicas-0                             1/1     Running   0               22h     10.244.0.12    minikube   <none>           <none>
redis                  redis-replicas-1                             1/1     Running   0               22h     10.244.0.14    minikube   <none>           <none>
redis                  redis-replicas-2                             1/1     Running   0               22h     10.244.0.15    minikube   <none>           <none>
```

I tried first to connect on desktop app with a portforward on redis-master :

```py
kubectl port-forward -n redis svc/redis-master 8080:6379
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 6379
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 6379
Handling connection for 8080
```

for the description of redis service:

```py
kubectl describe service redis -n redis
Name:              redis-headless
Namespace:         redis
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/instance=redis
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=redis
                   helm.sh/chart=redis-17.14.3
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/instance=redis,app.kubernetes.io/name=redis
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                None
IPs:               None
Port:              tcp-redis  6379/TCP
TargetPort:        redis/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.12:6379,10.244.0.13:6379,10.244.0.14:6379 + 1 more...
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

Name:              redis-master
Namespace:         redis
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/component=master
                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=redis
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=redis
                   helm.sh/chart=redis-17.14.3
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/component=master,app.kubernetes.io/instance=redis,app.kubernetes.io/name=redis
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.96.27.187
IPs:               10.96.27.187
Port:              tcp-redis  6379/TCP
TargetPort:        redis/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.13:6379
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

Name:              redis-replicas
Namespace:         redis
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/component=replica
                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=redis
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=redis
                   helm.sh/chart=redis-17.14.3
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/component=replica,app.kubernetes.io/instance=redis,app.kubernetes.io/name=redis
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.104.12.70
IPs:               10.104.12.70
Port:              tcp-redis  6379/TCP
TargetPort:        redis/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.12:6379,10.244.0.14:6379,10.244.0.15:6379
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

when I try to connect to redis in the redis insight UI I got this (I tried port forward on the pod directly too instead of the service)

host : 127.0.0.1
port : 8080
no password
[image]

after that I deployed redisinsight directly in my minikube and try to connect it with internal host
with the first yaml there https://docs.redis.com/latest/ri/installing/install-k8s/

[image: redisinsight pod]

there my script pulumi-python where I declare the helm chart deployment of redis database :

```py
import pulumi


from pulumi_kubernetes import Provider
from pulumi_kubernetes.helm.v3 import Chart, ChartOpts,FetchOpts
from pulumi_kubernetes.core.v1 import Namespace
from functions import ConfigYML


redis_namespace = Namespace("redis",metadata={'name':"redis"})



redis_chart = Chart(
    "redis",
    ChartOpts(
        chart="redis",
        fetch_opts=FetchOpts(
            repo="https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami",  # Updated repository
        ),

        namespace=redis_namespace.metadata["name"],
        values={
            "usePassword": False,
        },
    ),
    pulumi.ResourceOptions(depends_on=[redis_namespace])
)
```

`usePassword` is `false` I shouldn't have any password to set
furthermore in my terminal when I try to connect to the database with `redis-cli` command it seem working

```py
redis-cli -h localhost -p 8080
localhost:8080>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your setup. You need to set `auth.enabled` to `False` to disable authentication for Redis Bitnami chart.

Here's a sample setup:

```py
import pulumi
import pulumi_kubernetes as kubernetes

config = pulumi.Config()
k8s_namespace = config.get("k8sNamespace", "default")
app_labels = {
    "app": "redis-app",
}

# Create a namespace (user supplies the name of the namespace)
redis_ns = kubernetes.core.v1.Namespace(
    "redis",
    metadata=kubernetes.meta.v1.ObjectMetaArgs(
        labels=app_labels,
        name=k8s_namespace,
    )
)


# Use Helm to install the Redis chart
redis_chart = kubernetes.helm.v3.Release(
    "redis",
    chart="redis",
    namespace=redis_ns.metadata.name,
    repository_opts=kubernetes.helm.v3.RepositoryOptsArgs(
        repo="https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami",
    ),
    skip_crds=True,
    # values={
    #     "usePassword": False
    # }
    values={
        "auth": {
            "enabled": False
        }
    }
)

# Export some values for use elsewhere
pulumi.export("name", redis_chart.name)
```

Pods:

```
$ k get po -n redis                                                                                                                                                                                                
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
redis-69a473da-master-0     1/1     Running   0          6m12s
redis-69a473da-replicas-0   1/1     Running   0          6m12s
redis-69a473da-replicas-1   1/1     Running   0          5m35s
redis-69a473da-replicas-2   1/1     Running   0          5m13s
```

Portforward:

```
$ k port-forward -n redis redis-69a473da-master-0 8081:6379                                                                                                                                                       
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8081 -> 6379
Forwarding from [::1]:8081 -> 6379
Handling connection for 8081
```

Redis cli:

```
$ redis-cli -p 8081
127.0.0.1:8081>
```

RedisInsight v2 addition:
[image]

When I set `usePassword` to `False` and don't pass `auth.enabled`, I get redis with authentication enabled.

redis-cli when bitnami chart uses `usePassword=False` instead of `auth.enabled=False`:

```
$ redis-cli -p 8081                                                                                                                                                                                                
127.0.0.1:8081> KEYS *
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
```

Regarding the redis-cli connection at the end, did any commands succeed, or you got any protocol errors? It could be that redis-cli connected to RedisInsight v2's 8080 port or any other existing service that uses 8080 tcp port.